# Neural Network Standalone application in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification, prediction

How do I create a pre-trained standalone application in MATLAB?

I used the workspace to run the code. I will like to create a standalone application so as to share with others without MATLAB to test the neural network.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. One of the most important things you'll learn there is to **do your own research** and show it to us. People are more likely to help you when you show effort, and with more information on what you have already tried, we can help you more specifically. Please [edit] the question accordingly, preferably with what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

By stand-alone application, I am guessing that you want to create a GUI (Graphical User Interface) that people can use to test images on your network. If this is the case, you can either use the [GUIDE](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/creating-a-gui-with-guide-68979.html) or [App Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer.html) frameworks that MATLAB offers.

Note, however, if you plan on using MATLAB to develop this UI, the user will need MATLAB Runtime installed because you are coding in MATLAB. Just as if you created a program in python, the user would need python in order to run the program.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I meant.. If I ran for example the following in MATLAB's workspace: [x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = feedforwardnet(10);
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,y,t)  ......I will now have a pre-trained network. How do I save the pre-trained network as a desktop application/standalone so that I can share the pre-trained network with others to test the network for classification/prediction. Thanks.